# Importing .PEM certificates on Windows 7 on the command line

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, certificate

I need to import a [PEM certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-enhanced_Electronic_Mail) on a massive number of freshly installed Windows 7 Enterprise machines.

Normally, I would do it through MMC → Certificates (Local Computer) snap-in → Trusted Root Certificates → Import, but I need to speed things up. Therefore, I'd like to use only the command prompt.

With `certmgr.exe` (not `certmgr.msc`!), I would type:

```
certmgr.exe -add -c C:\certificate.pem -s -r localMachine root
```

The problem is that `certmgr.exe` does not exist in Windows 7. How then can I add a certificate from the command line?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to use `certutil.exe` instead:

```
certutil –addstore -enterprise –f "Root" <pathtocertificatefile>
```

will add the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.

If you want to add an Intermediate Certification Authority, replace `Root` with `CA` and to add to your Personal store, change it to `My`.

All the above adds the certificate to the Local Computer store.  To add to the User store remove the `-enterprise` from the command line:

```
certutil –addstore –f "Root" <pathtocertificatefile>
```

The `-f` in the command simply forces an overwrite in the case where the certificate is already installed.

Comment: One of the most useful answers I've seen for a long time, especially with the additional hints.  Upvoted.

Comment: Where to get certutil.exe ? The only links I found are for 32bit only

Comment: On every Windows computer :-)  It should be installed by default on every Windows installation.

Comment: *To add to the User store remove the -enterprise*: Removing `-enterprise` appears to try add it to the machine store and `-user` was required to choose the user store.  Maybe things changed in Windows 10.  Here's the relevant doc: *Use `-user` to access a user store instead of a machine store.*--https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil